# Is there a GOOGLE DOCS API for Android

Tags: android, google-docs-api

I am looking for a Google DOCS not DRIVE API for ANDORID. All the tutorials online seem to only be about google drive and google sheets. i would like the app to be able to send the data let say a paragraph to google docs so that i can edit it anywhere. after a few days i would like my app to just retrieve the google doc with a id and then be able to view the contents.

I could also like to know if you could create and retrieve GOOGLE DOCS document using the DDRIVE API for ANDORID.

Or am I supposed to use the REST API for GOOGLE DOCS using raw http requests?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Android library for Google Docs API.

But, there is a Java client for Docs API, which you can use in Android. Here's the official guide: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/java

For your second question: Drive API for Android is now deprecated ([given here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)), so it's best to switch to Docs REST API. Of course, you can use its Android client to avoid making direct/raw HTTP requests (as I mentioned above).

Comment: what is the name of the library

Comment: You'll need three libraries: `com.google.api-client:google-api-client`, `com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty`, and `com.google.apis:google-api-services-docs` as it's given in the link in the answer.

Comment: ok more question. in the google drive api upload section, how do you specify that it is a google docs file and not a .txt file

Comment: Since it's Docs API, it will auto-create Google Docs only, and not a text file. Here's the reference for its `create`: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create

Comment: In the Java Quickstart official guide, what is meant by "prepare the project"? Don't you already have your project (your app, in your app directory in Android Studio)? And what does "your working directory" mean?

Comment: @RedKnight Please ask your question as a new question on StackOverflow. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask